# Monte Carlo simulation to price an Option in Python

Tags: python, finance, simulation

In what ways can I make this code more efficient?

1. I haven't put in comments and descriptions yet. I need to do that.
2. Ideally, I'd like to make the S, v, r, and K user entered as I did with T. I'm worried this is going to make the program cluttered though.
3. Is it possible to put this entire thing into a class to make it more streamlined? Ideally, I would like for someone to just open the program and it does everything at once instead of having to fiddle with the individual functions.
4. Since there are a lot of iterations to be done in the simulation, I want some sort of progress to be printed to the console so the user knows it is working and didn't "blow up" so to say. I've done this in a sort of rag-tag way, but is there a way to make it more clean and nicer?
5. I'd like to work on the readability of this program.

```
import datetime
import time as walltime
from random import gauss
from math import exp, sqrt

S = 863.00 # underlying price
v = 0.20 # vol of 20.00%
r = 0.0218 # 10 year rate of 2.18$

while True:
    t0 = raw_input("Enter a valid number of days (as an integer) until expiration: ")
    try:
        t0 = int(t0)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if type(t0) == int:
        break
T = t0/ 365.0
K = 860.00
simulations = 100000000
payoffs = []
discount_factor = exp(-r * T)


def generate_asset_price(S,v,r,T):
    return S * exp((r - 0.5 * v**2) * T + v * sqrt(T) * gauss(0,1.0))

asset_price = generate_asset_price(S,v,r,T)

#print asset_price 

def call_payoff(S_T, k):
    return max(S_T - k, 0.0)

#print call_payoff(S,K)

"""Use to price a put instead of call"""
#def put_payoff(S_T,k):
#   return max(k - S_T, 0.0)

print "\n"
print "Working, please wait..."
print "\n"

cl1 = walltime.clock() 

count = 1
for i in xrange(simulations):
    S_T = generate_asset_price(S,v,r,T)
    payoffs.append(call_payoff(S_T, K))
    count += 1
    if count == 10000000:
        print "10 percent done"
    elif count == 25000000:
        print "25 percent done"
    elif count == 50000000:
        print "50 percent done"
    elif count == 75000000:
        print "75 percent done"

print "---------------------------"

cl2 = walltime.clock()
print "---------------------------"
print "End of computations, calculation time = ", (cl2-cl1), " sec"
print "---------------------------"
price = discount_factor * (sum(payoffs) / float(simulations))
print "Option Price: %.4f" % price
print "---------------------------"
```